# How to update React component automatically?

Tags: reactjs

I have 3 components which is responsible for handling details of a shopping cart. Once items are added, they will display on the cart as below screenshot

[image]

When I click on the + button of each item, the quantity value is incrementing by 1 in the database(MongoDB). But it will not update here automatically. If go some where else(eg: to loging page) and come back to the Cart, it will display with the updated value.

How Can I solve this issue? Massive thanks!

Components in order:-

Cart.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState} from 'react';

import Titles  from "../Titles";
import CartColumns from './CartColumns';
import EmptyCart  from "./EmptyCart";

import CartList from "./CartList";
import CartTotals from "./CartTotals"
import NavBar from "../NavBar";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {Redirect} from "react-router-dom";
import Axios from "axios";

const mapStateToProps = ({ session}) => ({
    session
});

const Cart = ({session}) => {

    const [Cart, setCart] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if(session.userId !== null){

            Axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/cart/getCart', {params:{userId: session.userId}})
                .then(res => {
                    const cart = res.data;

                    let tempProducts = [];
                    cart.forEach(item => {
                        const singleItem = {...item};
                        tempProducts = [...tempProducts, singleItem];
                    });

                    setCart(tempProducts);
                })
        }

    }, []);

        if(session.username !== null){

            return (
                <section>
                    <NavBar />
                        {(Cart.length > 0) ? (
                                    <React.Fragment>
                                        <Titles name ="Your " title = "Cart">Cart</Titles>
                                        <CartColumns/>
                                        <CartList cart = {Cart}/>
                                        <CartTotals value={Cart}/>
                                    </React.Fragment>
                            ) : (
                                    <EmptyCart/>
                            )
                        }
                </section>
            );
        } else {
            return(
                <Redirect to="/login" />
            );
        }
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps
)(Cart);
```

CartList.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import CartItem from './CartItem';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import Axios from "axios";

const mapStateToProps = ({ session}) => ({
    session
});

const CartList = ({session, ...props}) => {

    const cart = props.cart;

    const increment = (productId) => {
        const item = {
            userId : session.userId,
            productId: productId
        };

        Axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/cart/increment', item)
            .then(res=>{
                if(res.status === 200){
                    console.log('Incremented');
                }
            })
    };

    const decrement = (productId) => {
        const item = {
            userId : session.userId,
            productId: productId
        };

        Axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/cart/decrement', item)
            .then(res=>{
                if(res.status === 200){
                    console.log('Decremented');
                }
            })
    };

    return (
        <div className="container-fluid">
            {cart.map(item => {
                return <CartItem key = {item.id} item={item} increment={increment} decrement={decrement}/>
            })}

        </div>
    );
};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps
)(CartList);
```

CartItem.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from "react-redux";

const mapStateToProps = ({ session}) => ({
    session
});

const CartItem = ({session ,...props}) => {

    const {id,name, price, quantity} =  props.item;
    const {increment, decrement} = props;

    return (
        <div className="row my-2 text-capitalize text-center">
            <div className="col-10 mx-auto col-lg-2">
                <img  style={{width: '5rem', height: '5rem'}} className="img-fluid" alt="product "/>
            </div>
            <div className="col-10 mx-auto col-lg-2">
                <span className="d-lg-none">Product: </span>{name}
            </div>
            <div className="col-10 mx-auto col-lg-2">
                <span className="d-lg-none">Price: </span>{price}
            </div>
            <div className="col-10 mx-auto col-lg-2 my-2 my-lg-0">
                <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
                     <div>
                         <span className="btn btn-black mx-1" onClick={() => decrement(id)}>-</span>
                         <span className="btn btn-black mx-1">{quantity}</span>
                         <span className="btn btn-black mx-1" onClick={() => increment(id)}>+</span>
                     </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-10 mx-auto col-lg-2">
                <div className="cart-icon" >
                    <i className="fas fa-trash"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-10 mx-auto col-lg-2">
                <srong>Total: ${50}</srong>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps
)(CartItem);
```

Comment: The reason the incremented value is not showing is because, after updating the values, the components are not re-rendering. That needs to be done by calling setCart function to trigger render.

Comment: Can you please provide me an example please? @kay

Comment: you need to increment the `cart` in `cart.js` from the `increment` function in `cartlist.js`

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do it? @MuhammadUsamaAshraf

Comment: Move Increment and decrement function in Cart.js and pass them down to children like 
`<CartList cart = {Cart} increment={increment} decrement={decrement}/>`
And in function, once the post is successful, call setCart() and update the cart object or reload the cart object as you did in useEffect.

Comment: Okay I implemented the ```increment``` method inside the Cart.js and passed as you suggested. But no changes occur on the UI. DB is getting updated as previous @kay

Comment: if possible create a codepen or codesandbox. It would be easier to look at code that way.